# A little error in Android launcher

Tags: android, duplicates, launcher

I install my launcher on my device. If I press home button and select my launcher always without opening my application, everything's OK. However, when firstly I start my application, then press home and select my launcher, it opens my application again and again. What should I do?

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.comeks.cocuktab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.comeks.cocuktab.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: from your description it's not clear what's happening and what you expect to happen. do you have two activities in your app, and the wrong one is started the second time?

Comment: I install my application. Firstly, 'I do not open the app'. I press home button. I choose my launcher and thick make default. There is no problem. However, firstly, 'I open the app'. Then, I press home button. My application opens again. So, when I quit from my app, I see whole activities that are opened.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it is your problem but try to but this in your aplication:

in Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:noHistory="true" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the manifest

```
<activity   
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```